# EF returns null for Navagation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two entity models "Course" and "Item" as you can see:

```
public class Course
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public ICollection<CategoryToCourse> Categories { get; set; }
  public ICollection<AuthorToCourse> Authors { get; set; }
  public Item Item { get; set; }

}
```

And:

```
public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
  public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

But here the 'item' variable is null.

```
var course = _context.Courses
            .Include(p => p.Item)
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == 2);
            if (course != null)
            {
              var item = course.Item;
            }
```

I was unable to spot the problem.
Here is database config (maybe it's helpful):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>(i =>
{
  i.Property(w => w.Price).HasColumnType("Money");
  i.HasKey(w => w.Id);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Course>(p =>
{
  p.HasKey(w => w.Id);
  p.HasOne<Item>(w => w.Item)
    .WithOne(w => w.Course)
    .HasForeignKey<Item>(w => w.Id);
});
```

Comment: This seems to be wrong: `.HasForeignKey<Item>(w => w.Id);` surely the Course's Id is not the FK for the Item? I think you need an ItemId property on the Course class that you set as the FK.

Comment: @juunas Would you please explain it completely, please? Because I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Actually my comment was a bit wrong, since you are specifying the FK on the Item entity, not the Course entity. But is it intended that the Item PK is also the FK to the Course?

Comment: @juunas Yes, it is. This problem turned into a really wierd problem since it works in other classes (Controllers) but does not work in only this controller.

Comment: Okay, well that is weird :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above configuration of ModelBuilder, we can see you used `Item.Id` wrongly as the `ForeignKey` to bind the Course.
You should set  `public int CourseRef { get; set; }` as the `ForeignKey` like codes below.

### Configuring One To One Relationships In Entity Framework Core

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CategoryToCourse> Categories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AuthorToCourse> Authors { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
public class Item 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int CourseRef { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasOne(a => a.Item)
    .WithOne(b => b.Course)
    .HasForeignKey<Item>(i => i.CourseRef);
```

Comment: Not worked: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_Items_Course_CourseRef". The conflict occurred in database "Z2H_DB", table "dbo.Course", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You are trying to insert a record with a value in the foreign key column that doesn't exist in the foreign table. Check the CourseRef value.